# google charts ruby How to create titles for axis?

Tags: ruby, google-visualization, roc, gchart

I am currently using the google charts ruby api to draw my ROC curve. You can currently see it here: http://prntscr.com/8gnokp. (Below is the code).

```
roc_curve = Gchart.scatter(
    :size => '600x400',
    :title => 'ROC curve',
    :data => [pts.collect { |x| x[0] }, pts.collect { |x| x[1] }],
    :axis_with_labels => ['x', 'y']
)
```

I know the API provides axis_labels, but I can't seem to find any axis titles. For example, I want the y axis title to be "True Positives", and the x axis title to be "False Positives". Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Have you take a look in the :legend option of the chart ?

Comment: Yes I have. It's not particularly what I was looking for, since a legend would not work for the x axis or y axis title